# GroupBy in combination with ngFor does not work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new for angular and Using the groupBy pipe together with ngFor for grouping objects and iterating over them only display grouping objects but not showing related child data.

Below only i can able to display date on header but related child data not showing where i did mistack not understand can some one help me please

### .ts:

```
 this.events = [{
      id: 1,
      category:'camera',
      title: 'First event',
      date: '2017-12-26'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      category:'accessories',
      title: 'Second event',
      date: '2017-12-27'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      category:'camera',
      title: 'Third event',
      date: '2017-12-26'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      category:'accessories',
      title: 'Fouth event',
      date: '2017-12-27'
    },{
      id: 5,
      category:'camera',
      title: 'Fifth event',
      date: '2017-12-26'
    }]
```

## .html:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item-group *ngFor="let group of events | groupBy:'date' ">
    <ion-item-divider color="light">
        {{ group.date }}
    </ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item>{{ group.title }}</ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
</ion-content>
```

### PipeTransform:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'groupBy' })
export class GroupbycategoryProvider implements PipeTransform {

  transform(collection: Array<any>, property: string): Array<any> {
    // prevents the application from breaking if the array of objects doesn't exist yet
    if (!collection) {
      return null;
    }
    const groupedCollection = collection.reduce((previous, current) => {
      if (!previous[current[property]]) {
        previous[current[property]] = [current];
      } else {
        previous[current[property]].push(current);
      }
      return previous;
    }, {});
    // this will return an array of objects, each object containing a group of objects
    return Object.keys(groupedCollection).map(date => ({ date, events: groupedCollection[date] }));
  }
}
```

Comment: are you passing the filtered data to child component?

Comment: above my html file <ion-item>{{ group.title }}</ion-item> not printing and  <ion-item-divider color="light">  {{ group.date }}</ion-item-divider> it's pringint

Comment: If any one understand my problem please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

GroupBy pipe returns an object of a key/value pair.
https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#groupby

You need to install the ngx-pipes first, installation process:
https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#installation

The last piece of code that works perfectly for your data structure:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let event of events | groupBy: 'date' | pairs">
    <div>Group Date: {{event[0]}}</div>
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let g of event[1]">
        <div>Task: {{g.title}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your pipe code like this then only it would filter your object by date

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'groupBy'
})
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(collection: Array<any>, property: string): Array<any> {
    // prevents the application from breaking if the array of objects doesn't exist yet
    if (!collection) {
      return null;
    }

   var data= collection.sort(function(a,b){

  return new Date(b[property]) - new Date(a[property]);
});
   return data; 
  }

}
```

Html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item-group *ngFor="let group of events | groupBy:'date' ">
    <ion-item-divider color="light">
        {{ group.date }}
    </ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item>{{ group.title }}</ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: <ion-item *ngFor="let event of events">{{ event .title }}</ion-item> how this line working i am not understnad

Comment: your pipe is returning object of array so you need to loop

Comment: Showing all data to each group

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245710/how-to-group-the-list-by-date/51247789?noredirect=1#comment89505889_51247789 link working fine

Comment: let me try and tell result

Comment: but one more problem here i want to show date at once  as header then related child data need to show under the dates but using you code i am getting dates to each row

Comment: i hope your understand what i said

Comment: your old pipe is fine if you want to groubBy