# Group Data and Select Data

Tags: json, angular, grouping

I want to group data from a json file by year. Then when a user selects the year in the drop down. It displays the data from that year. 
I would prefer to do this without a pipe.

Json:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "volume": 3423
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "month": "2017-04-01",
    "volume": 3413
}
{
    "id": 3,
    "month": "2017-05-01",
    "volume": 3233
}
{
    "id": 4,
    "month": "2017-06-01",
    "volume": 1232
}
{
    "id": 5,
    "month": "2017-07-01",
    "volume": 1000
}
{
    "id": 6,
    "month": "2018-08-01",
    "volume": 0
}
{
    "id": 7,
    "month": "2018-09-01",
    "volume": 0
}
{
    "id": 8,
    "month": "2018-10-01",
    "volume": 6043
}
{
    "id": 9,
    "month": "2018-11-01",
    "volume": 92387
}]
```

The data currently displays in a table. But it displays all the data. I want to seperate the data to 2017 data and 2018 data. By using the drop down I want the users to select one of the years. Thenthe corresponding data will appear. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group the list by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245710/how-to-group-the-list-by-date)

Comment: similar but not quite working. I need further assistance as that duplication has errors.