# Grouping List by Date

Tags: angular, typescript

I want display list grouping by date. Example like this image bellow but I don't have any idea how to make it working.

[image]

This is my example code and demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-card-example-jkuml3)

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let monthData of products">
<div class="upcoming-container">
      <div class="upcoming-container-title-section color">
        Group Month | {{monthData.date | date : 'MMMM yyyy' }}
      </div>
      <div class="upcoming-container-card-section">
        <div *ngFor="let card of products" class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 upcoming-container-card-item">
            <app-card [listData]="listData"></app-card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

card.component.ts

```
 _listData: listData;

  @Input()
  set listData(data: listData) {
    this._listData = data;
  }
  get listData() {
    return this._listData;
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

**card.component.html**

```
<div class="cards-list">

<div class="card 1">
  <div class="card_image"> <img src="https://i.redd.it/b3esnz5ra34y.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="card_title title-white">
    <p>{{listData.date | date: 'd MMM yyyy'}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245710/how-to-group-the-list-by-date ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not such `group by` feature is offered by `*ngFor`. You have to modify your logic to get it done.

in your `component.html` :

```
<div *ngFor="let monthData of resultData">
<div class="upcoming-container">
      <div class="upcoming-container-title-section color">
        Group Month | {{monthData.date | date : 'MMMM yyyy' }}
      </div>
      <div class="upcoming-container-card-section">
        <div  *ngFor="let card of monthData.products" class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 upcoming-container-card-item">
            <app-card [listData]="card"></app-card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in `component.ts` :

```
let data = new Set(this.products.map(item => item.date))
data.forEach((date)=>{
     this.resultData.push({
        date: date, 
        products: this.products.filter(i => i.date === date)
      })
})
```

Here is the working example :  [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-card-example-v4jwig)